# How to make Ctrl+Alt+Del switch directly to Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using Windows 7 for a long time, but I wish I could find a way to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>  to switch directly to the Task Manager. I think there's some way to do it in the Control Panel, but I just can't find it.

Comment: I agree with the other posters that the combination of Ctrl+Shift+Esc is the best idea. Changing the mapping of Cntrl+Alt+Del seems more trouble than it is worth. You can also quickly access task manager by right clicking on the taskbar (preferably a blank spot) and selecting "Start Task Manager" from the list.

Comment: For security reasons, it is impossible to change what Ctrl+Alt+Delete does

Comment: For security reasons, it's **difficult** to change the behaviour of Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but it's not **impossible**. If you're willing to put the effort, you can do it. You can do that by patching `msgina.dll`. GINA is responsible for handling the response to the secure attention key SAK (aka, Ctrl+Alt+Delete). By modifying it, you can make Ctrl+Alt+Delete do whatever you want. This goes without saying, but you need administrative access to the machine (very likely physical access is needed when replacing the old `msgina.dll`.

Comment: @Adnan `msgina.dll` is not used post Windows XP, it has been replaced with a new system.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, it's safe to assume that the new system can also be modified.

Comment: One could argue if you start patching the operating system yourself, you're no longer using "Windows 7". If you start going down that route then it's very easy - just pull the Delete and Esc keys off your keyboard and swap them round.

Answer (score 29):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> to access task manager directly

Answer (score 12):

You can't redirect it, however if you use the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> it will launch the task manager directly.

[Here is a nice big list](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7) of the keyboard shortcuts that Windows 7 supports and some of the programs that it comes with.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick way to launch Task Manager, if the keyboard key combinations (both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) does not work:

1. Just right click on the task-bar and there is an option of "Start Task Manager"
2. You can go to "Run" (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `taskmgr`; this will launch Task Manager

Comment: I have not used windows for quite some time, but shouldn't it be `WIN`+`R` instead of `CTRL`+`R`?

Comment: @Tim It is. I took the liberty of fixing that. Ctrl+R would be an application-level shortcut.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Hey could you tell me how you created the keyboard like boxes

Comment: @Firee Click "edit" below your answer and you'll see.